# C: Store reference to stack variable in array

Tags: c, reference, stack

I'm writing a program that's running on an embedded MCU, so all of my memory allocations are to the stack (no malloc()). I have a struct being created in a function and returned to a caller, and I'm trying to keep a reference to that variable in an array, prior to being returned.

The problem is that the variable stored in the array seems to be a copy of the variable returned to the caller, so they're not in sync. The code below illustrates the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[1];

int initalizeVariables() {
    int i = 0;
    ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[0] = &i;
    return i;
}

int main(void)
{
    int test = initalizeVariables();
    test = 1;
    printf ("Test: %d, ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[0]: %d\r\n", test, (int)*ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[0]);
}
```

This prints: Test: 1, ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[0]: 0

How can I keep "test" and "ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[0]" in sync without malloc() and pointers?

Comment: You can't do it. When the function returns, its local variables are all destroyed. Pointers to them become invalid.

Comment: If you don't have `malloc()` use global variables, not local variables.

Comment: You can also use `static int i = 0;`

Comment: And the other option is to create the variables in `main` (or whatever scope-level is needed) and pass pointers to them into the `initialize` function so that `initialize` can modify the values.

Comment: Also, to clarify, `test` receives a copy of what was the local variable `i`, while `ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[0]` contains a pointer to what was the original (but is now out of scope and garbage).

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianGibbons -- That works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a function that I can pass a pointer of `i` back into for storage in `ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES`. Here's the new code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int *ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[1];

int initalizeVariables() {
    int i = 0;
    return i;
}

void setInArray(int *i, int idx) {
    ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[idx] = i;
}

int main(void)
{
    int test = initalizeVariables();
    setInArray(&test, 0);
    test = 123;
    printf ("Test: %d, ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[0]: %d\r\n", test, *ARRAY_OF_VARIABLES[0]);
}
```

If there are any better ways to do this, please feel free to post them :).

Comment: You are not passing the pointer to i at all! You are passing a pointer to test, which is a different variable from i. Your initializeVariables function does nothing, you can replace it with return 0; Can you give a better example of what you are trying to do? Why use pointers if you have only static allocations? Why not work with global variables directly?